# Button for an action , Jquery

Tags: jquery, button

I have the following script in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/UyeLX/3/

is there any option to make a external navigation for the sliders?

i want a navigation bar on that slides to the correct content tab.

Can anybody please help me !!!!

Comment: Please clarify.  I do not understand the question.

Comment: Besides to clicking on the individual tabs to slide to the content, I would like an external navigation bar with buttons so i can navigate between the sliders. 

My question is how do I call the jQuery function with a html button so it goes to the correct slide?

Answer (score 0):

If your button has an ID or class, simply use something like

```
$(".selector").click(function(){ $("#tab").trigger("click"); });
```

That will trigger the click event on the element with the ID of "tab".

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I was trying something like that but what fuction do i need to call?
$(".clickme").click(function(){ $("#accordion").msAccordion({defaultid:3});});


doesnt work